# SSAS cube access from java

Tags: java, mdx, saas, cubes, olap4j

We are rewriting a .NET application with MDX, Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient. In Java it is not easy to connect to Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services, SSAS. We have 5 big MDX queries. Maybe to use this, as I understand, in [this](http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=103) case XML/A HTTP access for SQL Server Analysis should be configured correctly. But it is not configured yet. Could you please advise what case is appropriate:

1. JDBC + rewrite MDX to SQL
2. olap4j + configure XML/A HTTP access  for SQL Server Analysis
3. or any other good way

And how about performance?

Comment: The second one must be way to go. Set up your msmdpump.dll and run a query against olap4j.